# I'm trying to use OPENPYXL, I get this TYPE ERROR whenever i try to create an excel file

Tags: python, typeerror, openpyxl

I am learning from Youtube, even if I copy the same code that runs on his screen I get the error.
Even if I copy other solutions from the internet I get the same error whenever the program wants to create an excel file.

```
from openpyxl import workbook

wb=workbook()
ws=wb.active
ws.title="Sheet-1"

ws['A1']="Simple data"

wb.save("too_bad.xlsx")
```

I have a gut feeling that this code is only faulty on my computer. I hope this gut is wrong

Comment: Which line _exactly_ is the type error being raised? Please [edit] to post the complete and exact error message, it may have more information, you don't have to rely on your gut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python modules are type-sensitive, so it makes a difference if you use "workbook" or "Workbook". The bellow code should work now.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb=Workbook()
ws=wb.active
ws.title="Sheet-1"

ws['A1']="Simple data"

wb.save("too_bad.xlsx")
```

Comment: Damn this really was the issue 
Thanks, man. Big help